# What to run a .bat file from within RStudio

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, pdf, text

I am trying to convert a certain .txt file into .pdf using [Text2Pdf](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/).

They have provided a very elegant way of using the [Text2Pdf.bat](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/win95setup.php) file.

I tested it and it is working great.

I am getting my text file from the following function saved as code.R :

```
myFun <- function(.csv)
{
  sink('Dimension.txt')
  csv <- read.csv(.csv)
  dimValue <- dim(csv)
  print("The dimension of the dataset is:")
  print(dimValue)
  return(dimValue)
  sink('Dimension.txt', append=TRUE)
}
```

Now, I want to write another function that would take this text file (may not be in the same directory as the code.R file) and convert it into a pdf using the text2pdf.bat file.

How do I do that?

Comment: If you're running a .bat you're probably on Windows so `shell.exec' should run the .bat file.

Comment: @TylerRinker Can you please show me a working example?

Comment: Maybe: `shell.exec("c:\mypath\text2pdf.exe Dimension.txt > Dimension.pdf")`. You don't need .bat file, just run command.